# SQL SERVER 'Contains' didn't return the actual result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with sql server contain clause.I want to search the table contents with search word starting with '.' using conatins clause .

If i search with the pattern '.n', it returns all the filecontent starting with 'n' ,but this query didn't check for the pattern '.n'

```
SELECT    resumetb.ResumeCode
        , resumetb.ResumeOwnerName
        , resumetb.FileLocation
        , resumetb.UploadDate
        , resumetb.UserCode
FROM  tbResumeDetails AS resumetb 
WHERE contains (resumetb.FileContent,'".n*"')
```

If i search with the pattern '.net', the query returns the correct result.

```
SELECT    resumetb.ResumeCode
        , resumetb.ResumeOwnerName
        , resumetb.FileLocation
        , resumetb.UploadDate
        , resumetb.UserCode
FROM  tbResumeDetails AS resumetb 
WHERE contains (resumetb.FileContent,'".net*"')
```

Comment: does contains (resumetb.FileContent,'"\.n*"') solve this?

Comment: I think you're confusing `%` with `*`

Comment: 'Contains' doesn't support wildcard symbol '%',need to use '*

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard symbol in SQL is '%', not '*' (at least in the SQL I know). Try swapping the symbols.

Comment: 'Contains' doesn't support wildcard symbol '%',need to use '*'